# Create new records from a field with comma delimited values

Tags: mysql

I have a poorly created table I want to update. It is set up as

- ID
- Name
- Value

Because a given Name can have more than one value right now the Value field is varchar and populated with comma delimited values:

- 12,15,92

I would like to create an update or create table query that will make those into separate records so a table with

- ID | Name | Value
- 1  | Bob  | 5,6,9
- 2  | Alice| 5,9
- 3  | Ted  | 1

ends up as

- 1 | Bob   | 5
- 2 | Bob   | 6
- 3 | Bob   | 9
- 4 | Alice | 5
- 5 | Alice | 9
- 6 | Ted   | 1

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: @MarcB No, go back to sleep

Comment: @user364973 create new another table, then using php (or some another language, what you know),  in cycle, you can execute data from old table,  use `explode()` function and  retrieved result,  insert in new table. or something like this...

Comment: Hi thanks, I found a splitter function for just this purpose: http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-stored-procedure-split-delimited-string-into-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question but there is a mysql function for this, it name is **group_concat**, [you can see the function in the offical documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat),  [also you can see an example here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1683-mysql-for-each-group-retrieve-a-comma-separated-list-of-values-in-a-given-column)

Answer (score 1):

In searching online it appear this is a pretty common issue and I found one of several functions for splitting delimited fields into records here:

http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-stored-procedure-split-delimited-string-into-rows